# Using group_by to count difference in values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large df like the one below, where I want to know (using the terms in the made up df) know which id that have the same fruit for the longest period of time in this biannually event. I.e. the opportunity to hold a fruit only occurs every other year.

```
 df<-data.frame("id"=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
  "Year"=c(1981, 1981, 1985, 2011, 2011, 2013, 2015, 1921, 1923, 1955), 
 "fruit"=c("banana", "apple", "banana", "orange", "melon", "orange", 
            "orange", "melon", "melon", "melon"))
```

I have tried different kinds of `group_by`, and `cumsum` see below.

```
df<-df %>% mutate(year_diff=cumsum(c(1, diff(df$Year)>1))) 
df %>% group_by(id, fruit) %>% filter(year_diff==2)
```

And the one below (after reloading the df)

```
df %>% group_by(id, fruit) %>% mutate(year_diff=cumsum(c(1, diff(df$Year)>1)))
```

And played around with:

```
df %>% group_by(id, fruit) %>% mutate(summarise(n_years=n_distinct(Year)))
```

In the end I ideally want a tibble like the one below arranging the id's (with their fruits) in order of who have the most consecutive "holds" of a fruit in the events (over time). Remember that the event only takes place every other year.

```
id     fruit    occurence 
2      orange    3
3      melon     2
1      banana    1
1      apple     1
2      melon     1 
3      melon     1
```

I understand that there are several steps.

EDIT:
Maybe there is a way to modify this:

```
df %>% group_by(id, fruit) %>% summarise(n_years=n_distinct(Year)) %>% arrange(desc(n_years)) %>% ungroup()
```

so that it creates a new column in the original tibble (which I am unable to do, but you might be), and then I can filter consecutive events?

Comment: I'm not sure that I entirely understand the question. What are you trying to calculate for each fruit + ID group?

Comment: In the first code example try to swap the code lines `mutate` and `group_by` then `filter`.

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, I missread my own numbers. I'll edit that.

Comment: Then how do you select Banana and not apple ? Both of them have occurrence as 1.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have tried that as well. If you mean: `df %>% mutate(year_diff=cumsum(c(1, diff(df$Year)>1)))%>%group_by(id, fruit) %>% filter(year_diff==2)`

Comment: Why are there two years in IDs 1 and 2? And is ID 3 supposed to be 1921, 1923, and 1955?

Comment: @hmhensen Id 1 have banana for two consecutive events (and had apple during one event -you can hold more than one fruit at each event), and id 2 held an orange for three consecutive events and  a melon for one. It's correct that id 3 is in two consecutive events and then again once  more than 30 years later.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for helping me. I just fixed the missred digit, but now I've added  all results instead of just occurrence  >1. If there is anything else that will improve my question don hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we `arrange` rows by `id`, `fruit` and `Year` and create a new grouping variable (`group`) showing consecutive years for each `id` and `fruit` and then count the number of rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(id, fruit, Year) %>%
  group_by(id, fruit, group = cumsum(c(2, diff(Year)) != 2)) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


#    id fruit      n
#  <dbl> <fct>  <int>
#1     1 apple      1
#2     1 banana     1
#3     1 banana     1
#4     2 melon      1
#5     2 orange     3
#6     3 melon      2
#7     3 melon      1
```

Comment: Yey! Thank you! It works smoothly. Have a great weekend. You saved mine.